# What is my foursquare authentication, callback_url and application web site?

Tags: ios, oauth, callback, foursquare

I'm trying to integrate the foursquare API in my iPhone but am stuck on the very beginning: registering my app.

Its asking me for my `callback_url` and application web site in order to register my app and get my authentication code but I don't understand what I'm supposed to put in for those links since I don't have a domain name for this app. Its just an app with no web sites. I have been spending so many hours trying to figure out what to put in those two fields on the foursquare developer site but I have no idea what I need to do.
Anyone know what my `callback_url` and application website is if my iPhone app does not have a web site?

Answer (score 5):

When you create your own mobile application, it does not really matter what callback URL you enter. You can set the callback URL to any valid URL, but for security reasons it is favorable to use one under your control (so that nobody else can get the token).

Please see the Foursquare documentation for "Phone-based or client-side application": https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth

There is also a link to an iOS code sample that shows how the OAuth process can be done directly on the device: https://github.com/anoopr/core-data-talk/blob/master/example/Classes/FoursquareAuthViewController.m

Comment: When I try the method shown in the github code, after I allow the app access, the absoluteString for my webview is my www.appwebsite.com/f? and nothing else. No token or anything.

Comment: In the github code, I am just putting a valid url and I can see my access token in the webview safari page. However I also get a "server stopped responding error" and my webViewDidFinishLoad method never gets called