# How can I authenticate user using foursquare api?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, foursquare

I need to do a login system using the login from foursquare but I didn't found any tutorial about this

Comment: Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10396363/what-is-my-foursquare-authenticaion-callback-url-and-application-website

Comment: thx, it works. When user log in I get the token. But how can I get more infos from user? Infos how nickname or name, gender etc?

Comment: I already know. FSConnect take a NSDictionary with this infos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open source libray is available on Github for connecting to foursquare.
pls check:
https://github.com/baztokyo/foursquare-ios-api